# First example in [basic.lookup.unqual]/3

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

First example in [[basic.lookup.unqual]/3](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lookup.unqual#3):

```
int h;
void g();
namespace N {
  struct A {};
  template <class T> int f(T);
  template <class T> int g(T);
  template <class T> int h(T);
}

int x = f<N::A>(N::A());        // OK: lookup of f finds nothing, f treated as template name
int y = g<N::A>(N::A());        // OK: lookup of g finds a function, g treated as template name
int z = h<N::A>(N::A());        // error: h< does not begin a template-id
```

The comments above seem to indicate that the compiler should treat differently the lookups for the names `g` and `h`above, as if a *template-id* would not be considered for the name `h`. I can't see this difference when I compile this snippet with [clang](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/536752c1b7ff5cd8) or GCC. What is exactly the difference that the example is trying to convey?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking at the C++20 draft, but testing with a C++17 compiler.

Unqualified *template name* lookup is a new ADL feature introduced by [P0846R0](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/p0846r0.html) and adopted into the C++20 draft.

So to try it out, use GCC trunk with `-std=c++2a` ([link](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/T4XRqj)):

```
error: expected primary-expression before '>' token
   12 | int z = h<N::A>(N::A());        // error: h< does not begin a template-id
```

Granted the exact error message isn't yet perfect, the end result is that the first two lookups succeed.

To compare, notice that the C++17 version of [[basic.lookup.unqual]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.lookup.unqual#3) doesn't contain the example you mentioned.

Comment: Aha. Excellent example of why just referring to the latest draft wording is sometimes counter-productive!

Comment: That's not what I got [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1e5f00d45cc3e459).

Comment: Never mind. I got the same result as yours [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/bScHvKEz6oLhgdXb#result-container-tab-permlink). But what do you mean by "the error message isn't yet perfect"?

Comment: coliru runs GCC 8.2. The feature you want is in trunk only at the moment (9.0+). By error message I mean it should say something about `h` not being a template.

Comment: I am still confused. You said: `it should say something about `h` not being a template`. But `g` also is not a template. What's the difference? In other words, why does the compiler find `template <class T> int g(T);` in `N`, but can't find `template <class T> int h(T);` in namespace `N`?

Comment: I know why. It's because `h` is not a function. [basic.lookup.argdep]/(3.3) kicks in and the set Y is empty. Again, thanks for the great answer.